# div in grandchild don't handle onClick event by handler passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new on React & JS so grateful on some tips :-)
I have a grandfather stateful component App ,
a child stateless Drumpad who renders by a `.map()` a,
grandchild of App stateless Pad component.
i'm trying to pass the onClick handler `{handleClick}` as props from  App to Pad, but seems not work. I'm stuck various days with this :-(
here the code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(...props) {
     super(...props);
     this.state = {
        power: false,
        bank:"Smooth piano kit",
        display: "Pulsa cualquier tecla",
        volume: 30
     };
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    handleClick(e, props) {
      this.setState({
       display: this.props.id
      })
    }
    render() {
return (

  <div className="App">
    <Display display={this.state.display} />
    <div className="Switches">
      <Switch
        name="power"
        onSwitch={this.handleSwitchPower}/>
      <Switch
        name="bank"
        onSwitch={this.handleSwitchBank}/>
    </div>
    <Slider2
     value={this.state.volume}
     onSlide={this.handleOnSlide} />
    <Drumpad 
      bank={this.state.bank === "Heater kit"? sounds["Heater kit"]: sounds["Smooth piano kit"]}
      handleClick={this.handleClick}
      />
  </div>
);
  }

}

export default App;




// child component Drumpad


import React from "react"
import Pad from '../components/Pad.jsx'
// import {sounds, MODE_NAMES} from '../data/sounds-constants.js'


const Drumpad = props => (

    <div id='drum-machine'>
        <div>{props.bank.map(d => (
          <Pad
            key={d.name}
            id={d.name}
            letter={d.shortcut}
            src={d.link}
            handleClick={props.handleClick}/>   
         ))}
        </div>
    </div>
)
export default Drumpad



// grandchild component Pad

import React from "react"
import "../App.css"


const Pad = props => (
    <div 
        className='drum-pad'
        onClick={props.handleClick}
        >
        <h1 >{props.letter}</h1>
        <audio id={props.letter}
            className='clip'
            src={props.src}>
        </audio>
    </div>
)
export default Pad
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: How about changing `onClick` to `onClick={props.handleClick}` inside `Pad` component ?

Comment: yep you're right but was an error at copying the code changing it now .

Comment: not error , but code don't respond to the event

Comment: Have you tried using composition? [link]https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html, This should solve your problem the react way!

Answer (score 0):

In your grandchild, call the function, instead of passing it as a reference:

```
<div 
  className='drum-pad'
  onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id)}>
```

Also, if you care about accessibility, attaching click handlers to a div is basically wrong, so either use a button, or give div a `role="button"` attribute, while managing `aria-pressed` state on your own. Simpler to use a button

Comment: and how can i acces now to the props.id in the handler now?

Comment: solved !! thanks  how i can mark as solved?  this is the code ```onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id)}```  and ```handleClick(id) {
    this.setState({
      display: id
    })
  }```

Comment: while writing `{() => props.handleClick()}` you are not calling the function, instead still passing the reference which is the same as `{props.handleClick}` except for the context binding part

Comment: Correct, I tried to keep the terminology simple, instead of writing 'pass the reference to an anonymous functions that will trigger it when it gets triggered by a click event'! But yeah, you are right. @michelperez, there's a checkmark to the left of the answe, which is how you mark it as an accepted answer. I will modify it in a sec to include id passing as well